# Switch java home using /usr/libexec/java_home stop working after MacOS upgrade to Big Sur

Tags: java, java-home

I have a simple script to switch between different JDK versions. However, after MacOs upgrade to Big Sur, it stop working. Not sure if it's related to OS upgrade or not.

The script `setjavahome.sh`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v $1`
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Usually, I call
`. setjavahome.sh 1.8`

It will switch java home. But now it doesn't do anything.

If I use `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`, it's still able to list all the versions.

Just `/usr/libexec/java_home -v` stop working.

Not sure why it suddently stop working.

Comment: Do you know the tool [jEnv](https://www.jenv.be/)? It does exactly that and works very well with Mac and brew.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer to this question, but at least here's a workaround:

```sh
PROGRAM="{ if (\$1 ~ \"^$1.*\") print \$NF }"
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -V 2>&1 | awk "$PROGRAM"`
```